# проверка авторизации в телеграмм боте на Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, авторизация, telebot

Товарищи! Нужна ваша помочь! Не понимаю как сюда можно прикрутить авторизацию пользователей, чтоб писать боту Логин и Пароль, и бот мог в БД проверять наличие такой комбинации, и если она присутствует, давать на время доступ к своему функционалу

```
import telebot
import config

bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKKEN)

keyboard1 = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(True, True) 
keyboard1.row('Проверить Сделку', 'Правила проведения Сделок')
keyboard1.row('Официальные контакты', 'Техподдержка')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Начнем!', reply_markup=keyboard1)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['help']) 
def help_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, config.HELP)

 #  Декоратор для сообщений 
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_text(message):
    if message.text.lower() == 'проверить сделку':  # → авторизируйтесь → введите номер сделки
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите номер сделки')  #номер сделки, статус, рекомендации


elif message.text.lower() == 'правила проведения сделок':
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, config.rules)   

elif message.text.lower() == 'официальные контакты':
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'pass')

elif message.text.lower() == 'техподдержка':
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'чат')   # переключение на чат с техподдержкой

else:
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'what?')
```

Comment: Подключайте базу sql так лучше будет. Потому что при закрытии программ будет сохранятся все данные.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Делал подобного бота для вк, думаю для telegram несложно адаптировать поступал так:
Создавал в бд таблицу с авторизованными пользователями. Когда бот получает от пользователя правильные логин и пароль, то он добавляет id этого пользователя в таблицу. Когда приходит какая-то команда, которая доступна только при авторизации, то бот должен проверить есть ли пользователь с таким id в таблице и если он есть то команда выполняется иначе ответ "нет доступа". Соответственно при команде типа /logout пользователь удаляется из этой таблицы